# Highcharts xAxis formatter export to csv

Tags: highcharts

I have a formatter function in xAxis. When I export the data to csv, it generates 0,1,2 instead of the custom xAxis formatted data.

I'm using highcharts v7.1.2.

```
 xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Year'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        var months = ["Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May", "Jun.",
                            "Jul.", "Aug.", "Sep.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec."];

                        var day = this.value + 1;

                        var date= DateFromDay(2019, day);

                        return months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getDate();
                    }
                }
            }
```

How to get formatted data in export file. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Highcharts export `x` and `y` values of each point. Using `xAxis.labels.formatter` callback the axis labels can be modified but points values are the same.

This issue can be resolved by wrapping `Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getDataRows` method and modify the array with rows to export. Check demo and code posted below:

**Code:**

```
function formatXAxisLabels (value) {
    return value * 10 + "s";
}

(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getDataRows', function(proceed, multiLevelHeaders) {
    var rows = proceed.call(this, multiLevelHeaders);

    rows = rows.map(row => {
      if (H.defined(row.x)) {
        row[0] = formatXAxisLabels(row.x);
      }
      return row;
    });

    return rows;
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p3aL62u8/2/